# Create a column with numbers based on the values of another column

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
layer0_name <- c("1_10177_A_AC", "1_14599_T_A", "1_15903_G_GC","1_54712_TTTTC_T","1_54716_C_T")
layer1_name <- c("DDX11L1", "WASH7P","WASH7P","OR4F5","OR4F5")
df <- data.frame(layer0_name, layer1_name)
```

I want to create column with numbers. So, starting from 1, if layer1_name is the same then number remains the same otherwise goes to the next number. The desired output is the following:

```
layer0_name layer1_name Index
1_10177_A_AC    DDX11L1 1
1_14599_T_A WASH7P  2
1_15903_G_GC    WASH7P  2
1_54712_TTTTC_T OR4F5   3
1_54716_C_T OR4F5   3
```

I can't figure out how to do this, so I would really appreciate your help. I guess there should be an easy solution.

Comment: Perhaps using dplyr functions: `library(dplyr); df %>% mutate(Index = cumsum(layer1_name != lag(layer1_name, default = first(layer1_name))) + 1)`

Comment: There are lots of solutions in the linked answer. I like `library(dplyr); df %>% mutate(Index = cumsum(!duplicated(.$layer1_name)))`.